# shipping switzerland, europe - international regions - how to?

Tags: expresso-store

so this is my second store site I am developing. 
and I never did a store v2.x site - so my question might be obvious...

so my customer has defined 3 shipping options:
1. switzerland 10.-
2. europe 15.-
3. international 18.-

so I've thought I make 3 shipping methods with the "default shipping plugin":
1 switzerland (with country = switzerland)
2 europe
3 international

I think that could work rather well. Would you do that the same way?

Or would you rather create only one shipping option and then first put switzerland, then all the countries of europe, and leave the rest for international orders. I know that this method would involve more work at the beginning, but customers woudn't have to choose the shipping options themselfs and they coudn't cheat that way - am I right?

Do you have any tipps on what's the best way?
If the first option is best, maybe a word on how to preselect the shipping method automatically?

any help appreciated!
stephan

Answer (score 2):

Your second idea is correct. Since your shipping prices are fixed, you only need to have one "shipping method", and it can be preselected for all carts by default.

Inside the shipping method, you can add different rates for each country, and these will automatically be applied based on the shipping address of each order.

Comment: thanks a lot! so I went with your suggested workflow, bit in the sour apple and created these 30 rules. I think it's all good!

Comment: Just at the end I discovered a country named "Europe". What exactly is this for? Is this intended? I would really love to see continents as well ;)

Comment: It's not intended, probably a hangover from when Store used to use EE's built in country list (which had a few glaring inaccuracies). A clean install of Store 2.x doesn't have a country named Europe. Also, it won't behave as you expect (it will only match shipping rules if the customer also specified their shipping address as the country "Europe")